# Why this local variable can keep its value in the function

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I recently met a problem in Python.
Code:

```
 def f(a, L=[]):
   L.append(a)
   return L

 print f(1)
 print f(2)
 print f(3)
```

the output would be

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

but why the value in the local list: L in the function f remains unchanged?
Because L is a local variable, I think the output should be:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

I tried another way to implement this function:
Code:

```
def f(a, L=None):
  if L is None:
  L = []
  L.append(a)
  return L
```

This time, the output is:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

I just don't understand why...
Does anyone have some ideas? many thanks.

Comment: Read this http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default parameters are in fact initialized when the function is defined, so

```
def f(L = []): pass
```

is quite similar to

```
global default_L = []
def f(L = default_L): pass
```

You can see this way that it is the same list object that is used in every invocation of the function.

Comment: this is a very very useful piece of information. just saved me a bulky psychiatry bill. Yet, it is a very weird choice on python's part. I don't know if it's just me but this is horribly unintuitive.

Answer (score 3):

The list in `def f(a, L=[])` is defined as the function is defined. It is the same list every time you call the function without a keyword argument.

Setting the keyword to `None` and checking / creating as you have done is the usual work around for this sort of behaviour.